# Is there a way to auto-indent code inside playground in Pharo?

Tags: indentation, mathematical-optimization, smalltalk, pharo, auto-indent

I noticed, while playing with Pharo, that regardless of the way I type the code in playground, if I try to run it, but there is some problem, when the debugger opens it shows your code nicely indented.

For example, if I have this not particullary well indented program in playground:

```
| banditA banditB testBandits multiRun results |
banditA := [ 1.0 random <= 0.6 ifTrue: [ 1.0 ] ifFalse: [ 0.0 ] ].
banditB := [ 1.0 random > 0.6 ifTrue: [ 1.0 ] ifFalse: [ 0.0 ] ].

"Tests banditA and banditB n times each, to see which one is better."
testBandits := [ :n |
    | A B |.
    A := 0.0.
    B := 0.0.
    n timesRepeat: [ A := A + banditA value ].
    n timesRepeat: [ B := B + banditB value ].
    A  > B  
        ifTrue: [ { A + B . banditA} ]
        ifFalse: [ A < B 
                        ifTrue: [ { A + B . banditB} ]
                        ifFalse: [ { A + B . { banditA. banditB } atRandom  } ] ] ]. 

"Accumulate the results of size - 2 * nTests number of trials of winning
bandits, each preceded with a explore phase with 2 * nTests (half to each
bandit."
multiRun := [ :nTests :size |
    | testResults sum |
    sum := 0.0.
    testResults := (testBandits value: nTests).
    2 * nTests negated + size timesRepeat: [ sum := sum + (testResults at: 2) value ].
    sum ].

"Average the returns of a thousand runs, to each even number of tests between 1 and
size = 1000."
results := (1 to: 500) collect:
    [ :n | { 2*n. ((1 to: 1000) collect: [ :each | multiRun value: n value: 1000]) average}].

Transcript clear; show: 'Number of tests;Return'; cr.
results do: [ :each | Transcript show: (each at: 1); show: ';'; show: (each at: 2); cr ].

results sorted: [ :first :second | (first at: 2) > (second at: 2) ]
```

If I open the debugger in this code sample with Ctrl+Shift+D, the debugger shows me a nicely formated DoIt object, minus the comments:

```
DoIt
    | banditA banditB testBandits multiRun results |
    banditA := [ 1.0 random <= 0.6
        ifTrue: [ 1.0 ]
        ifFalse: [ 0.0 ] ].
    banditB := [ 1.0 random > 0.6
        ifTrue: [ 1.0 ]
        ifFalse: [ 0.0 ] ].
    testBandits := [ :n | 
    | A B |
    A := 0.0.
    B := 0.0.
    n timesRepeat: [ A := A + banditA value ].
    n timesRepeat: [ B := B + banditB value ].
    A > B
        ifTrue: [ {(A + B).
            banditA} ]
        ifFalse: [ A < B
                ifTrue: [ {(A + B).
                    banditB} ]
                ifFalse: [ {(A + B).
                    {banditA.
                    banditB} atRandom} ] ] ].
    multiRun := [ :nTests :size | 
    | testResults sum |
    sum := 0.0.
    testResults := testBandits value: nTests.
    2 * nTests negated + size
        timesRepeat: [ sum := sum + (testResults at: 2) value ].
    sum ].
    results := (1 to: 500)
        collect: [ :n | 
            {(2 * n).
            ((1 to: 1000) collect: [ :each | multiRun value: n value: 1000 ])
                average} ].
    Transcript
        clear;
        show: 'Number of tests;Return';
        cr.
    results
        do: [ :each | 
            Transcript
                show: (each at: 1);
                show: ';';
                show: (each at: 2);
                cr ].
    ^ results sorted: [ :first :second | (first at: 2) > (second at: 2) ]
```

After some digging, I discovered there is a option to format source code inside the class browser, just by right-clicking source code, then choosing Source code > Format code:

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to do the same to source code inside playground, as the Source code > Format code option is not shown on right-click. If I try the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-T inside playground, it just erases whatever is selected. I could just copy code from playground into the browser, format it there, and then copy it back to playground, or could just open the debugger on the sample and then copy the nicely formated code into the playground, erasing the DoIt top line and the return symbol ^ from the expression in the last line, but that's not convenient. So I'd like to know if there is a proper way.

By the way, the code sample I used as a example is my attempt at simulating a instance of the [Multi-armed bandit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) used in a psychological experiment described in the book [Algorithms to Live By: The Computer Science of Human Decisions](https://algorithmstoliveby.com/#aboutthebook):

> "Once you become familiar with them, it’s easy to see multi-armed
> bandits just about everywhere we turn. It’s rare that we make an
> isolated decision, where the outcome doesn’t provide us with any
> information that we’ll use to make other decisions in the future. So
> it’s natural to ask, as we did with optimal stopping, how well people
> generally tend to solve these problems—a question that has been
> extensively explored in the laboratory by psychologists and behavioral
> economists. In general, it seems that people tend to over-explore—to
> favor the new disproportionately over the best. In a simple
> demonstration of this phenomenon, published in 1966, Amos Tversky and
> Ward Edwards conducted experiments where people were shown a box with
> two lights on it and told that each light would turn on a fixed (but
> unknown) percentage of the time. They were then given 1,000
> opportunities either to observe which light came on, or to place a bet
> on the outcome without getting to observe it. (Unlike a more
> traditional bandit problem setup, here one could not make a “pull”
> that was both wager and observation at once; participants would not
> learn whether their bets had paid off until the end.) This is pure
> exploration vs. exploitation, pitting the gaining of information
> squarely against the use of it. For the most part, people adopted a
> sensible strategy of observing for a while, then placing bets on what
> seemed like the best outcome—but they consistently spent a lot more
> time observing than they should have. How much more time? In one
> experiment, one light came on 60% of the time and the other 40% of the
> time, a difference neither particularly blatant nor particularly
> subtle. In that case, people chose to observe 505 times, on average,
> placing bets the other 495 times. But the math says they should have
> started to bet after just 38 observations—leaving 962 chances to cash
> in."

I'd like to see if I could arrive at this figure of 38 as a optimal number, so I wrote this simulation. Arrived pretty close, this plot shows the results of one run:

[image]

This particular run resulted in a maximum at 34, quite close to 38. There is some variation between runs, as the curve gets a bit noisy in the top, but the maximum is consistently less than ten positions away of 38.

Comment: If the code you write in the Playground is long enough as to require formatting for the sake of clarity, it means that your work requires that you create some class(es) and methods. That way your script would be greatly simplified by creating instances of your class(es) and sending them messages after the methods you implemented.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia thank you. The issue is, after I split code in classes and methods, it becomes less convenient to share it just by coping and pasting a block of text inside a email or a blog post. While trying to do it, I discovered fileout, but then the text gets longer, and information like my name is printed as well, requiring futher editing. I still couldn't figure the proper way to do it. It's possible to copy and paste individual methods, as I see people doing in many questions, but then some assembly is required if others want to reproduce. In playground you can just copy, paste & run.

Comment: I don't see any problem with author names being included in fileouts. Do you? Moreover, there are different ways of sharing code/projects that the Smalltalk community uses and enjoys. You should learn and use them before trying to invent another one from your own.

Comment: I have to again completely agree with Leandro :).  You Workspace code is doing way to much.  You should be able to split it into smaller chunks and then try the stuff in the Workspace only the part you are intersted in.  To me it feels like you are trying to fit the whole program into Workspace, which is never a good idea.  One more thing, use proper variable names.  In the future it will make your life easier because you won't have to decrypt what does `A`, `B`, `n` mean and how does it relate to banditA, banditB.